# VBA dynamically distribute values across range

Tags: vba, excel, dynamic

I'm trying to build on a previous work which distributes values based on ranking. the code below works but assumes there would always be three rows to rank.

**Sample Image & Code**

[image]

```
Sub distrib()

Set R1 = ActiveSheet.UsedRange     
M = 62

For i = 2 To UBound(T1)
    If T1(i, 2) > 0 Then
        V = T1(i, 2)
        If V <= M Then
            For j = i To i + 2
                If T1(j, 1) = 1 Then
                    T1(j, 3) = V
                Else
                    T1(j, 3) = 0
                End If
            Next j
        Else
            A = M
            V = V - M
            If V > M Then
                B = M
                V = V - M
                If V > M Then
                    C = M
                Else
                    C = V
                End If
            Else
                B = V
                C = 0
            End If
            For j = i To i + 2
                Select Case T1(j, 1)
                    Case Is = 1
                        T1(j, 3) = A
                    Case Is = 2
                        T1(j, 3) = B
                    Case Is = 3
                        T1(j, 3) = C
                End Select
            Next j
        End If
    End If 
Next i

For i = 2 To UBound(T1)
    Cells(i, 3) = T1(i, 3) 
Next i

End Sub
```

**Ideal Outcome:** i need a way to make the distribution dynamic in response to the row height or `loop` value.

The logic should determine how wide the range is (i.e. `loop` value) and distribute the values across range based on rank, with the max of each cell not exceeding 62 . *see image below*

Thanks so much for any help and happy to provide clarification.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the loop values in column D are already there, I think this will work.

```
Sub x()

Dim r As Range, rDist As Range, n As Variant, i As Long, wf As WorksheetFunction

Const nMax As Long = 62
Set wf = WorksheetFunction

For Each r In Range("D2", Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    Set rDist = r.Offset(, -3).Resize(r.Value, 3)
    For i = 1 To r
        n = Application.Match(i, rDist.Columns(1), 0)
        If IsNumeric(n) Then
            If wf.Max(rDist.Columns(2)) - wf.Sum(rDist.Columns(3)) < nMax Then
                rDist(n, 3) = wf.Max(rDist.Columns(2)) - wf.Sum(rDist.Columns(3))
                Exit For
            Else
                rDist(n, 3) = nMax
            End If
        End If
    Next i
Next r

Columns(3).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Value = 0

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much @SJR. can you explain what the details of the innermost IF statement? i gather some of the logic, but would like to understand the thought behind.

Comment: My pleasure. The inner loop works out the difference between the total in the values column and the sum of the values so far in the distribution column. If the difference is less than 62 it puts the whole amount in the relevant cell and exits the loop; otherwise it adds the 62 to the relevant cell and continues to the next rank. Clear?